# Extract multiline output if consist certain word AND inside a bracket

Tags: perl, awk, grep

I have an input of such:

```
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[79987] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:115 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: (
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
)
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[79987] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:151 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
```

There's two case to be matched here, one is of multi-line, another is of single line. The criteria is that it must have the `DEBUG:` keyword. For multiline, if that line has the keyword and and a `(`, then it should match until the end of `)`. Each line is separated by a newline separator. I can't figure this out. Currently I'm using a simple `grep DEBUG:` and that's it. But for the multi-line scenario, everything is lost beside the first one. And I'm not familiar with `perl`, any idea? Thanks in advance!

Note that I'm on iOS (jailbroken), thus another tool might be limited.

EDIT:

Expected output will be the whole line that matched the criteria, that's the same as the input example shown above. The actual input have tonnes of other lines that doesn't have the keyword `DEBUG:`, and thus will be ignored.

Comment: What is the expected output for the input you show? Also there are no curly brackets in your input

Comment: Edited. It's the same as the example shown input, as the actual input that doesn't have to keyword will be omitted. Put simply, I wanted to filter out the content that have the DEBUG: keyword (multiline or single line)

Comment: How do you separate a single line from a multiline case? For the multiline case, where does it end? With the a single closing parenthesis `)` ?

Comment: Sorry, just edited that too! Yes, it is

Comment: Perhaps you could use an expression like https://regex101.com/r/DDdwra/1/ Can you add the code that you use to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'f; /\)/{f=0} /DEBUG:/{print; f=/\(/}' file
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[79987] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:115 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: (
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
)
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[79987] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:151 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
```

Explanation:

```
awk '       # WHILE read line DO 
f;          #    IF the flag `f` is set THEN print the current line ENDIF
/\)/{f=0}   #    IF the current line contains `)` THEN clear the flag ENDIF
/DEBUG:/ {  #    IF the current line contains `DEBUG:` THEN
    print;  #        print the line
    f=/\(/  #        set the flag `f` to 1 if the line contains `(`, 0 otherwise
}           #    ENDIF
' file      # ENDWHILE
```

Comment: I didn't expect `awk` could do this especially if there's two conditions to be met (i.e. single and multiline), this is a very good solution as I intended to use it on terminal. If you don't mind could you explain briefly explain the syntax? Understanding it beyond me.

Comment: OK, I added an explanation as pseudo code next to each statement. In UNIX for simplicy,  clarity, portability, etc. if you need to do `s/old/new` then use sed; if you need to do `g/re/p` then use grep, for any other text manipulation use awk, and for anything that's more than just text manipulation such as manipulating (creating/destroying/moving) files, manipulating processes, sockets, calling other tools, etc. that you'd otherwise do in shell THEN consider perl, python, ruby, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using a Regexp in Perl (but this should probably be handled more accurately by a parser like [`Regexp::Grammars`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars)):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do { local $/; <> };
my @lines = $data 
  =~ /
         ^( (?:(?!$).)* DEBUG:
             (?: 
                 (?: [^(]*? $ ) 
              | 
                 (?: (?:(?!$).)* \( [^)]* \) .*? $ )
             )
         )/gmsx;

say for @lines;
```